# Getting Dynamic Data in Lua

Tags: c#, lua, connect, nvidia

I have built an Instrumentation Cluster with the NVIDIA UI Composer Studio. 
To control animations it uses the Lua Scripting Language. Now I'm really new to Lua and my question is the following:

I've got the following Code sequence in Lua which controls my Speedometer:

`self.vehicleSpeedData = {}`  -- A lot of Values are put in here

```
function self.speedSim( inFrame, theController )

local timeInSec, dummy
timeInSec, dummy = getElapsedTime()
-- data based on 60fps
actualFrameNumber = math.floor(timeInSec * 60)
local theSample = ((actualFrameNumber-1) % #self.vehicleSpeedData) + 1
theController.value = self.vehicleSpeedData[theSample] *0.06
```

end

The array in this example is empty. So as you can see, the function reads out the Values of the Array.

But what I need is, that I can get this Data from an external Source (Such as RS232 or CAN Simulation) ... What I want to try is, if I can put Data from C# for example to that Lua Script.

It is hard do explain what I exactly want. My idea is that this Lua Script above listens and reads Data which I dynamically read in C# from my Data Source.

Thanks a lot for your help. This work is for my Bachelors Degree and I'm stuck at this point a long time and I'm nearly out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all kind of depends on what that Nvidia thing exposes to the user (in terms of API, and Lua base libraries).

Assuming it is available, you can use `io.read` to read in a datafile (say a csv) from another source, then parse it yourself into your table. If you can preprocess the file to have a valid Lua syntax (eg prepend a `return {`, have values separated by `,` , and end with a `}`, you could directly load the string with loadstring).

If they allow you to, you could use external libraries for interfacing with RS232, Excel, sockets, whatever.

PS: it's Lua not LUA (not an acronym, but the Portuguese noun for Moon ;))

**Edit: example mkfifo**

so in Linux it goes like this: make a fifo with `mkfifo fff` and feed it something echo ' '> fff to prevent Lua from blocking.

In Lua:

```
fh=io.open('fff','rb')
while true do
    res = fh:read()
    if res then
        print(res)
    end
end
```

Whatever cat into fff (eg `cat 10 > fff`) will come out in Lua. this way you can read out any available values and use them at each run of your function.

Another option is using standard input, but I'm not sure whether this composer thing lets you.

Comment: That way is possible for sure. I think NVIDIA has it's own Interpreter included in the Composer Studio. Now I don't know how far it allows me to use external libs. 
Using io.read is not that effective. The data will be about 100 values per second or more. I cannot save a file this often, reopen it and read the values out of it.
That's what I mean with dynamically. It must read the values in time and use them immediatly. 

Any ideas?

P.S. I will call it Lua now :-)

Comment: I don't know zip about Windows (please forgive I blindly assume you use windows ;)) but in Linux, you can make a fifo file to read from, or read from standard input (eg using nc to stream data from the network). On current hardware, it would strongly surprise me if 100 values will be a problem. But I guess, try the easy solution first, benchmark where the issue lies, and only then try and solve it.

Comment: That is my point. Yes I use Windows because the Studio only runs on Windows. There's a possibility to compile it for Linux (what my goal is, because I must run it on an NVIDIA Tegra 2 Chip with an Embedded Linux on it)... I hope this will work then. 
I am not that good in programming, I understand code really good, and I know what you mean, but can you give me an example how this could work ?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I hope your Bachelor's Degree turned out alright, what with this response being 1.5 years too late. :) Nonetheless:</sub>

As a member of the UI Composer team and a fellow Lua scripter, one technique I use often for streaming external data and events asynchronously into the runtime is to use the [Lua Socket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) library. I have written an abstraction layer on top of it as a UIC behavior.

```lua
-- Expected message structure:
-- "<numbytes>,<optionaltag>\n<bytesofmessage>"
-- e.g. "11,simple\nHello World"
-- e.g. "40,\nThis has no tag,\nbut does have a newline"

local ok,socket = pcall(require,'socket')
if not ok then
    output("Error loading socket: "..socket)
else
    local output = output or print
    local sscallbacks = {} -- indexed by simplesocket instance, then tag
    SimpleSocket = {}
    local SSMeta = {}
    SSMeta.__index=SSMeta

    function SimpleSocket:server(port,ip,timeout)
        return self:create('server',port,ip,timeout)
    end

    function SimpleSocket:client(port,ip,timeout)
        return self:create('client',port,ip,timeout)
    end

    function SimpleSocket:create(kind,port,ip,timeout)
        if not port    then port    = 51423 end
        if not ip      then ip      = '*'   end
        if not timeout then timeout = 10    end
        local ss = setmetatable({
            kind    = kind,
            ip      = ip,
            port    = port,
            timeout = timeout/1000,
            queue   = {}
        },SSMeta)
        sscallbacks[ss] = {}
        return ss
    end

    function SSMeta:destroy()
        if self.socket then self.socket:close() end
        callbacks[self] = nil
    end

    function SSMeta:onData(callback,tag)
        self:setCallback('handler',callback,tag)
    end

    function SSMeta:toEncode(callback,tag)
        self:setCallback('encoder',callback,tag)
    end

    function SSMeta:toDecode(callback,tag)
        self:setCallback('decoder',callback,tag)
    end

    function SSMeta:setCallback(type,callback,tag)
        if not tag then tag = "" end
        if not sscallbacks[self][tag] then sscallbacks[self][tag] = {} end
        sscallbacks[self][tag][type] = callback
    end

    function self:onUpdate()
        self:sendQueuedMessages()
        self:receiveMessages()
    end

    function SSMeta:createSocket()
        output("Creating new "..self.kind.." socket to "..self.ip..":"..self.port)
        if self.kind=='server' then
            self.socket = assert(socket.bind(self.ip,self.port))
            self.socket:settimeout(self.timeout)
        else
            self.socket = assert(socket.connect(self.ip,self.port))
        end
    end

    -- Attempts to send all messages from the queue
    function self:sendQueuedMessages()
        for ss,_ in pairs(sscallbacks) do
            while ss.queue[1] do
                if ss:sendMessage(message[1]) then
                    table.remove(ss.queue,1)
                else
                    -- don't attempt any later messages, since ordering may be important
                    return 
                end
            end
        end
    end

    function self:receiveMessages()
        for ss,callbacks in pairs(sscallbacks) do
            if ss.kind=='client' then
                if not ss.socket then ss:createSocket() end
                ss.socket:settimeout(0) -- non-blocking for first byte
                local char1, err = ss.socket:receive(1)
                ss.socket:settimeout(ss.timeout) -- go back to blocking
                if not char1 then
                    -- probably just timed out
                else
                    local header, err = ss.socket:receive('*l')
                    if not header then
                        output(err)
                    else
                        header = char1..header
                        local comma = header:find(',')
                        local bytes = tonumber(header:sub(1,comma-1))
                        local tag   = header:sub(comma+1)
                        local data,err = ss.socket:receive(bytes)
                        if not data then
                            output(err)
                        else
                            if callbacks[tag] and callbacks[tag].decoder then
                                data = callbacks[tag].decoder(data)
                            elseif callbacks[true] and callbacks[true].decoder then
                                data = callbacks[true].decoder(data)
                            end
                            if callbacks[tag] and callbacks[tag].handler then
                                callbacks[tag].handler(data)
                            elseif callbacks[true] and callbacks[true].handler then
                                callbacks[true].handler(data)
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    function SSMeta:send(data,tag)
        return self:sendMessage(self:encodeMessage(data,tag))
    end

    function SSMeta:ensureSend(data,tag)
        local message = self:encodeMessage(data,tag)
        if not self:sendMessage(message) then
            table.insert(self.queue,message)
        end
    end

    -- Internal only; use send() or ensureSend()
    function SSMeta:sendMessage(formattedMessage)
        if not self.socket then self:createSocket() end
        if not self.client then self.client = self.socket:accept() end
        if self.client then
            local lastbyte,err = self.client:send(formattedMessage)
            if lastbyte then
                -- TODO: verify that all bytes were sent
                return true
            else
                output(err)
                self.client:close()
                self.client = nil
            end
        else
            -- No client connected before the timeout
        end
    end

    function SSMeta:encodeMessage(data,tag)
        data = tostring(data)
        local callbacks = sscallbacks[self]
        if callbacks[tag] and callbacks[tag].encoder then
            data = callbacks[tag].encoder(data)
        elseif callbacks[true] and callbacks[true].encoder then
            data = callbacks[true].encoder(data)
        end
        return tostring(#data)..","..(tag or "").."\n"..data
    end

end
```

This allows multiple different systems to communicate on the same socket, with different tagged communication, and possibly different encoders/decoders to serialize/deserialize the data.

On the receiving end this is used for example like this:

```lua
local ss = require 'SimpleSocket'

local client = ss:client()
client:onData(function(d) print("Client got *: "..d) end,true)
```